# Cursor type in plpgsql storedprocs

Tags: postgresql

I have an oracle procedure that takes 2 string arrays as inputs and 2 cursors. Can I convert that to Postgres stored proc with input refcursor?.

Also for example, if the input array is speed1 character varying[]
book--is a table

SELECT count(disply) into STRICT a_count FROM BOOK WHERE speed in (SELECT unnest(speed1));

am I using unnest properly?
when I try to RAISE NOTICE of display it is showing as 0 but, I know there are records.

Thanks,
Vana

I have a table similar to this.

```
TABLE t_i_s_lookup with columns
t_d_value,  TEXT
 m_l_h_speed   TEXT
 t_display  TEXT
I have procedure that gets an array of strings as input and gives the result set out in a cursor. When i run the below coode it gets compiled . I am testing this with the block below and I am always getting count as 0 from raise notice.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE t_pkg_get_h_v_text ( in_h_speed CHARACTER VARYING[] ,inout out_h_display refcursor , inout error_code text , inout error_text  text ) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $body$
DECLARE
v_state   TEXT;
    v_msg     TEXT;
    v_detail  TEXT;
    v_hint    TEXT;
    v_context TEXT;
 h_count bigint;
 
BEGIN
BEGIN
    
SELECT count(t_d_value) into STRICT h_count FROM T_I_S_LOOKUP WHERE m_l_h_speed in (SELECT unnest(in_h_speed));
RAISE NOTICE 'Count = %', h_count;
IF h_count > 0 THEN
OPEN out_h_display FOR
SELECT a.t_display_value FROM T_I_S_LOOKUP a WHERE a.m_l_h_speed in (select * from unnest(in_h_speed) as alias0);
ELSE
OPEN out_h_display FOR
SELECT a.t_display_value FROM T_I_S_LOOKUP a WHERE a.m_l_h_speed = 'DEF_HSIA';
-- FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 9>";
--RAISE NOTICE '%',out_h_display;
END IF;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can, but your question is so unclear that I don't know what else to answer.

Comment: I am not getting edit option. I am posting another question.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: You can certainly [edit] your own question.